# Creating category and sub category with nested json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

**I am trying to create a flutter app which shows category and items based on selected Category. here i am able to fetch category but struck in fetching items, can someone please help me solve this.. here is my code**

```
class ListElement {
  ListElement({
    this.catId,
    this.categoryName,
    this.item,
  });

  String catId;
  String categoryName;
  List<Item> item;

  factory ListElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListElement(
        catId: json["cat_id"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        item: List<Item>.from(json["item"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
      );
}

class Item {
  Item({
    this.itemId,
    this.itemName,
  });

  String itemId;
  String itemName;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        itemId: json["item_id"],
        itemName: json["item_name"],
      );

}
```

**here is the code to fetch category**

```
Future<List<ListElement>> showCatagory() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var category = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List data = category['details']['list'];
        return data.map((e) => ListElement.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        return List<ListElement>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return List<ListElement>();
    }
  }


FutureBuilder(
      future: showCatagory(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        }
    );
```

**here is nested json:**

```
list: [
    {
      cat_id: "517",
      category_name: "Pizza",
      item: [
        {
         itemId: '1',
         itemName: 'name'
        },
        {
         itemId: '2',
         itemName: 'name'
        },
      ],
    },
    {
    //other items
    }
   ]
```

[image]
any help for at least getting list of products will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error with your current implementation?

Comment: No, i'm able to get all the categories listed in UI but not sure how to get items to be shown in UI base on that category(pic attached), any suggestion?

Comment: List items = List();
      
       Map result = jsonDecode(json);
      result["list"].forEach((category)=>
                         category["items"].forEach((it)=>items.add(it)));
    
        items.forEach((item)=>print("${item["itemName"]}"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post here the code to access the items:

```
List items = List(); 
Map result = jsonDecode(json); 

result["list"].forEach(
(category)=> category["items"].forEach(
(it)=> items.add(it)
)
); 

items.forEach((item)=>print("${item["itemName"]}"));
```